# How to send large size of the caption on telegram bot using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telegram-bot

Hi i am working on telegram bot sync with my app and sending the image with caption. i am getting success for sending image on the telegram bot.but when i am sending long caption with image half of it is not getting passed.i don't know if any limit of the caption or text send on telegram i have no idea about it. please any one know then please tell me.i want to send full caption with image. my caption is long then  i want to make 2 part of the caption and send it. here below i have try like this code.

This my api =>

```
  [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public void SendCasesOnTelegramBot()
    {            
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Setting.ConnectionString(), "GetPostForTelegramBot");
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0] != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    var Image = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Url"].ToString();
                    byte[] imageData = null;
                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                    imageData = webClient.DownloadData(Image);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();                        
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(".");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(".");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString().Length <= 133)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString().Substring(0, 133));
                        sb.AppendLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString().Substring(134, 0));
                    }
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("join our team...");

                    Bot.SendPhotoAsync("@abc", new FileToSend(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Url"].ToString(), ms), sb.ToString());                      
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
        }
    }
```

This is my caption =>

```
**it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).**
```

any one please help me i have not idea how can do that.

Comment: you can't set a caption with more than 200 characters. you may send a photo and then reply it with a text message containing your desired long text.

Comment: @tashakori so it's limit there up to 200 characters don't set in the caption right??

Comment: Yea,you can't have that long text included in the caption.

Comment: i have check just only go there 133 characters  only on the bot so it's correct?

Comment: Maybe you have some emojis or other special characters in your text.

Comment: so here now no any other way for the send large text above 200 chr ? with image \

Comment: No you can't do it with a single message. As i  mentioned before, you may use 2 messages to do this. First send your image, then reply to that message with your text.

Comment: @tashakori Hi i have one question so can you please help me i want to uplaod video on telegram bot so how can do that? please give me hint i have ask question also on here

Comment: @tashakori i have one confusion here on telegram bot so can i ask?

Comment: Hi, please publish your question, so that, you can benefit from the stackoverflow community and you can gather more attention and also you may have more luck in finding answer for your problem. by the way, i will be around and if i know the answer i will reply your question;-)

Comment: @tashakori i want to some need suggestion related telegram bot . i need to create chat module on the bot. for ex. i have one bot name of "Abc".so i want to first show some list of show user in the bot and i have select one user then that time chating will start in the bot. so it's possible with c#?

Comment: feasibility of your project is not bound to the language. Yea, you can use c#, if you prefer.

Comment: @tashakori but how can do have you idea? i have found many link but i don't getting with c# any link or some hint so can you please guide me for some idea.

Comment: I'm not a c# programmer, so I can't give you hints based on the language. BTW take a look at thr below link and start with creating very simple bots and playing around with different features of the telegram api. Then you may come with ideas of how to implement your bot. https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot

Comment: @tashakori ok thanks for helping me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @tashakori said, you can send only 1024 char in caption.

There is a way to dirty pass it, use `sendMessage` instead of `sendPhoto`, and use `HTML` or `Markdown` to put photo file link in first char (can be emoji).
Your photo will show as preview, and you can put up to 4096 char as caption.

BTW, you can't use bold/italic in photo caption, but you can use it now. :)

Comment: From recent tests I did, Telegram has increased caption size to 1024 chars.

Comment: @AmitP is right, caption limit now is 1024 symbols and emojis are treated as one character.